# Angular material: no background color on mat-input on focus mode

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

[image]

I have a mat-input field

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input class='formulaInput' matInput [(ngModel)]='mathFormulaInput'>
  </mat-form-field>
```

and I am not happy with the blue background when it is focused on. Is there a simple CSS way of hiding this?

Comment: `input:focus { background: none; }` try this

Comment: There should not be a background color, have a look at the examples [here](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples). Can you post the CSS for the component and/or any global rules which might affect this?

Comment: BY default it will not show any background, maybe some of your css overriding it, please post your css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with angular-material, but with your browser. Check the "user agent stylesheets". Most likely this comes from the browsers autofill ( input:-internal-autofill-selected) styles.

Comment: Indeed, it only shows when I use some autofill suggestion. My bad. Thanks for the input!

Comment: You can overwrite those styles, see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:-webkit-autofill

Comment: @RaphaelMayer it gets me to a 404 :(